# How to get the order details of the guest user in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, sales-order, customer-session

I want to get the order details of the customer. For logged in customer i have no problem. But how to get the order details for the guest users.

Thanks!.

Comment: You can't get details from a guest user until we purchase something. Then you can get by his email.

Comment: upvote for good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For  guest , magento have it `customer_id as null`.So you need to `sales model by guest email address and magento set a flag`customer_is_guest =1`whenever customer will checkout as guest.`

**Note:** Magento  also  save `Customer email address` to  `sales model` table whenever l`oggin customers` are checkout  ,so on this case  `customer_is_guest =1`  is importand

```
    $orderCollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$Customeremail)
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_is_guest',1) ->addFieldToSelect('*');
foreach( $orderCollection  as $eachorder){
//var_dump($eachOrder)
}
```